# Need a wordpress plugin for store and show trainee information in grid view

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

For a training center website i need a wordpress plugin that can store trainee information like name, batch no, phone no, email and a picture. That i can show in a page in grid view. please suggest me some wordpress plugin or any other way that i can do it. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you must use WordPress for this (not ideal) then one way is to register your trainee as a user and use a user meta plugin such as Meta Box to add additional fields to the user page: https://wordpress.org/plugins/meta-box/

Then use the get_user_meta function to retrieve the stored values and display them on a page: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta

Answer (score 0):

My favourite way is with custom post types. It might be a bit more work than installing some plugin and forgetting, but you are in control of everything and can adjust your code as needed.

1. Generate code for post type - https://generatewp.com/post-type/
2. Add it to your functions.php
3. Install ACF - https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/
   and add the fields to your custom post type.
4. Add some users from the admin to the trainee post type
5. Select your trainee users and print them out.

Some links that might be usefull:

- Post type templates so you can print out all trainees on trainy archive page - https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates
  (You can skip this and add the post selection loop and printing out in some other page.)
- How to get yout trainee posts - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/query-for-custom-post-type
- ACF get_field() function to get custom post data https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/